# Facebook Canvas crossdomain.xml issue: Rejected because no crossdomain.xml policy file was found

Tags: php, facebook, canvas, crossdomain.xml

I'm trying to use unity3d WWW class to execute php from a facebook Canvas app (the .unity3d is in a https as mandated by facebook). I made sure to place a crossdomain.xml file in the root of my domain (www.mydomain.com/crossdomain.xml) where the php files are. I also ensured I can access it from the web, all is fine. However, I get a "Rejected because no crossdomain.xml policy file was found" from the unity webplayer in Canvas

Tried to access the php from a regular webplayer (outside of Facebook Canvas) and it works fine! Any ideas!

Here's my code for crossdomain.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I checked various posts, non of the tricks there are working

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where it was working fine in the editor but wouldn't work on the Facebook Canvas.

I was able to solve this by adding the `crossdomain.xml` file to both the root of the php server AND where the unity binary file was stored